# Android - Releasing memory of bitmaps

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

I think this question is asked often enough but after I did

```
bitmap.release;
bitmap = null;
```

in *onDestroy* of a Fragment, there is as much memory used as before.

The Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initializeViews();
    croppedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/.../0001.jpeg");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
    fabCreate.setOnClickListener(...); //never called
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    clearMemory();
    super.onDestroy();

}
void clearMemory(){

    fabCreate.setOnClickListener(null);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    imageView = null;
    croppedBitmap.recycle();
    croppedBitmap = null;
    java.lang.System.gc();
}
```

Comment: Does something else have a reference to it?  Is there a memory leak?  DId the GC actually run?  Any of these could be the problem.

Comment: @GabeSechan The Bitmap is used in an Imageview. But before I recycle the Bitmap I set the imageBitmap from the imageView to null. And there is also no change after calling System.gc();

Comment: System.gc is a recommendation, it isn't enforced.  But you could have a memory leak in your app in general keeping a reference to it alive somewhere.  It also depends on your version of Android-  where bitmap memory is kept has changed a few times.

Comment: @GabeSechan I edited my question. There isn't much in the Fragment so I don't no where there is an memory leak...

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
if(bitmap != null){
   bitmap.recycle();
   bitmap = null;
}
```

For more info read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715442/android-free-up-bitmap-memory-resources-programmatically)

Comment: What is that supposed to achieve?

Comment: According to the documentation bitmap.recycle(); releases the native heap that is used in bitmaps. And setting it to null is to assist the GC to quickly collect your reference

Comment: As I said in my question, this doesn't work for me. But I don't know why.