# Possible to Force Garbage Collection in Android ?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

in Android Running time `Android Monitor` will Show the Memory Usage. that Panel have a `initiate Garbage Collection`Button while pressing that Button Memory will reduce. my question is programmatically initiate that Garbage initiation.[**Before CG**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYmVz.png) and 
[**After CG**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFS4b.png)

Comment: You can do it, but it has totally no sense. You will just waste CPU time on it. GC will be called on it's own once needed. You should not call it manually.

Comment: Then how to prevent from OOM ??

Comment: @NatheemYousuf - OOM is almost always due to your usage of bitmaps. So, the answer is to learn to better manage your bitmap memory. [Here is my answer to that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42519335/199364); you can find many other answers also. google "android manage bitmap memory".

Comment: And ... there is a good chance that running the GC manually won't prevent the OOME anyway.  An OOME only happens immediately after the GC has been run ...

Comment: @Stephen C: This isn't a duplicate. Could you please remove your "This question already has answers here:".

Comment: This is a better duplink.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177802

Comment: And I have added a new answer there ...

Comment: GC is called before OOM is thrown. This is guaranteed. It is therefore futile to call it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

This line of code does not guarantee that garbage collector will be called. But it usually is as far as I can see.

And actually you don't need it. You should ensure you have no leaks and let GC work on it's own.