# How to clear memory in android? Memory increasing while switching between activities

Tags: java, android, memory

Is there a good way to clear memory in *android*? Because if I do this the memory is still increasing while I switch between activities.

```
public class Resurces extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView wikipedia1,wikipedia2,googlemaps,googlePhotos;

    private void clearMemory(){
        wikipedia1.setOnClickListener(null);
        wikipedia2.setOnClickListener(null);
        googlemaps.setOnClickListener(null);
        googlePhotos.setOnClickListener(null);

        wikipedia2 = null;
        wikipedia1 = null;
        googlePhotos = null;
        googlemaps = null;

        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try{
            clearMemory();
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            finish();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to try to force garbage collection.  In fact, it's kind of a waste of effort.  The GC is highly optimized on modern versions of Android and will do the right thing so that you don't run out of memory, unless of course your app is actually using too much memory.  Don't worry about the increasing memory - that is natural as an app encounters new code.  It will come back down once it reaches a threshold determined by Android.

See also:

- [Garbage collector in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117429/garbage-collector-in-android)
- [Garbage Collection in android (Done manually)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177802/garbage-collection-in-android-done-manually?lq=1)

Comment: got it thank you.... but what about assigning values to null is it good or there is better way to clean memory ?

Comment: Don't worry about it.  The GC will free the memory when they are no longer used.