# System.gc will work in android(Andengine)

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, andengine

I developing a game using andengine. In J2me game when exit , i made all object as null

ie:

```
Image img;
Sprite s1;

When exit application , 

img=null;
s1=null;
```

In android i will use System.gc() or i need to make all texture, textureRegion and sprite as make as null, when exit appliaction ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do either at exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java garbage collection should take care of that. You don't need to do that.

However I would close open connections, file handles, etc..

[System.gc()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29) is just a hint to the JVM that garbage collection is suggested, however Java is running it at its own will.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should not call `System.gc()` explicitly. Android OS takes care of that.

**"Calling `System.gc()` from your app is like providing electricity connection from your home to light up your complete society's lights"**

I mean it slows down your app to clean all the garbages of the system.......

Comment: I've run into a situation where calling System.gc() does prevent an OutOfMemoryError when bitmaps are tight in the external heap, so there are definitely some cases where it helps. Ideally, efficient loading and unloading of bitmaps would prevent the need, but from my recent experience that can be very difficult when many large images need to be loaded on a device with a small heap limit. I don't believe System.gc() is as pointless as the quote suggests, it's more like having an uninterruptible power supply with enough juice to power the house for a minute.

Answer (score 0):

In **Android in the presence of a garbage collector**, it is never good practice to manually call the GC. A GC is organized around heuristic algorithms which work best when left to their own devices. Calling the GC manually often decreases performance.

Occasionally, in some relatively rare situations, one may find that a particular GC gets it wrong, and a manual call to the GC may then improves things, performance-wise. This is because it is not really possible to implement a "perfect" GC which will manage memory optimally in all cases. Such situations are hard to predict and depend on many subtle implementation details. The "good practice" is to let the GC run by itself; a manual call to the GC is the exception, which should be envisioned only after an actual performance issue has been duly witnessed.

**It's better to spend more effort in avoiding the unnecessary creation of objects (like creation of objects inside loops)..**

Look at the Question [Garbage collector in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117429/garbage-collector-in-android)