# Is it possible to wait for GC_FOR_ALLOCATION to complete?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, garbage-collection

Im having a little problem in my Libgdx Android game. When I change the screen, animation starts as soon as new screen created. It works perfectly fine and smooth on the Desktop, but when i run this on android device, the lag appears when new screen created and it looks like a few frames of animation are just skipped.

After some investigation i discovered that this is because creating new screen invokes many new images and other objects to be created, therefore GC_FOR_ALLOC was invoked several times:

```
04-23 20:26:11.411: D/dalvikvm(18461): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 385K, 48% free 8809K/16880K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
04-23 20:26:11.531: D/dalvikvm(18461): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 454K, 48% free 8867K/16880K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
04-23 20:26:11.651: D/dalvikvm(18461): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 475K, 48% free 8903K/16880K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
04-23 20:26:11.746: D/dalvikvm(18461): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 473K, 48% free 8942K/16880K, paused 12ms, total 13ms
04-23 20:26:11.856: D/dalvikvm(18461): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 481K, 47% free 8967K/16880K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
```

**So my question is:**
Can I somehow make my app wait for these operations to complete and only after that launch the animation?

In fact, I need the ability to get the garbage collectors 'state' or something, so that I could start animation *after* gc has finished its allocation operations.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Libgdx but i see it has a [Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getFramesPerSecond--) method so maybe you can start your animation only when FPS stabilizes.
If that method takes too long to give a suitable average perhaps you can measure your own FPS from start with [getRawDeltaTime()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getRawDeltaTime--).

Comment: Omg, you just solved my issue by mentioning getRawDeltaTime()! Previously I was calling render method with getDeltaTime() parametr, which returns smoothed value for _n_ last frames! As creating a new scene takes long time, average frame duration has increased for a while. And that was what I called a lag! Calling render method with getRawDeltaTime() solved that, as this method returns exact difference between two frames without smoothing! It appeared that I understood my problem wrong, garbage collector finished its job in the same frame when new screen was created :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.gc()`. Documentation:

> When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine
>   has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

See [Waiting for GC to finish before starting game with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751749/waiting-for-gc-to-finish-before-starting-game-with-java)

Comment: Thanks, but i have already tried that. This method has no use for me, as GC_FOR_ALLOC operations are invoked _during_ creation of a new screen and it freezes a few frames in the beginning. It happens even if `System.gc()` called before initialization of a new screen. I need a way to tell my game to hold on until garbage collector is done.