# OutOfMemory for Animation in ViewFlipper

Tags: java, android, android-layout, memory, memory-management

I know there are many questions, forums about OOM in Android in different situations, but I couldn't find a complete solution.

I have an activity where the user can scroll between many animations. Since only the animation should move when scrolling and at the beginning it must move without the user interaction, I used a ViewFlipper with the animations inside. As the image bellow schematically shows:
[image]

The problem is that on tablets and devices above 3.0 it throw OOM after flipping some animations and playing them. What I tried until now, in order to solve the problem:

1. I scaled down the animation images using `BitmapFactory.Options` (I
   followed the tutorial [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently
   tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)). The only thing I didn't implement from the tutorial is the caching.
2. Since there are many animations, so many bitmaps, I
   loaded only 3 animation at a time (the current view, the one on the
   left and the one on the right), but adding and removing bitmaps has
   slowed down too much the app.
3. I tried to make the garbage collector to release faster my images, by manually calling everything that could help: `setCallback(null)`, `setImageDrawable(null)`, `destroy()`, `destroyDrawingCache()`  (the last 2 for AdView). I even tryed `recycle()` (for Bitmaps), but it caused other exception

After the above changes there is some improvement, but I still **receive OOM on an emulator Android 4.x WVGA854 or WVGA800** (after a longer period of time). But even when it doesn't trow OOM, the memory profiling shows 80% loading on the devices that were problematic to begin with. In addition the user experience is bad on all devices due to anim removal and addition.

I am starting to think is more an architecture/design problem. **It might be an emulator problem? Do you now better memory profilers than the one in DDMS perspective?**

I would be very grateful for any suggestion, I don't know what else to try:)

Comment: have you tried to use system.gc()?

Comment: Thank you! As I said bellow, it seems that we should try to avoid that call as this questions(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117429/garbage-collector-in-android) shows. But I will try it to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

usually I'm using this to prevent the out of memory problem

```
bmp.recycle();
bmp = null;
System.runFinalization();
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
System.gc();
```

I'm calling it after I used the bitmap

if it's still didn't work maybe you should try it in the real device

Comment: Thanks, I tried bmp.recycle, but I didn't really help (Do you also need to load many bitmaps in the same activity?). Regarding System.gc() I read that is not ok to call it because there is a complex algorithm of recycling and by manually calling the GC that algorithm becomes useless, so I avoided.

Comment: hmmmm,yes I need to load many bitmaps in the same activity, and system.gc() solved it,but if you don't want to use it maybe some other solution like using fragments?have you tried it?

Comment: Framents seem like a very good idea, I will try that. Thank you very much NAYOSO:)